# Trying to get match data from Xbox API

Tags: api, xbox

Hello I'm having some trouble with the Xbox API. Does anyone know how I can view a users recent online game data. Nothing major just the user they played against and the result.

Answer (score 0):

This information isn't available from Microsoft, its usually held by the games developer. For example Fifa is held by EA Sports.

Basically, if the Xbox mobile or desktop app can get the information, then so can I (usually).

~djekl

Comment: Ok, I see. So how would I got about getting it from EA if that is even possible??

Comment: You would need to look at the EA apps, and see if you can get the data you want from there. I have never looked at them, so wouldn't know if its possible